# Comparing 2 exact same strings result false? 

Tags: android, string, compare

I have a weird problem... I use this code:

```
    String text = new String(values[0]);
    Log.e("TEST", "|" + text + "|" + new String(values[0]) + "|");
    if (text == "pong") {
        Log.e("TEST", "2|" + new String(values[0]) + "|");
        receivedresponse = true;
    } else {
        Log.e("TEST", "1|" + new String(values[0]) + "|");
        myToast.setText(new String(values[0]));
        myToast.show();
    }
```

values = 112,111,110,103

String(values[0]) = "pong"

text = new String(values[0]) = "pong"

still text != "pong"... however "pong" == "pong"?

-

Anyone knows why?

Comment: text.compareTo("pong") seemed to work!

Any idea why it has to be this way? I did like to learn :)

Comment: You have .equals() in java. do not use ==. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: Thanks! Usefull information, should have answered instead...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In java you need to use `.equals` on the string:

```
   text.equals("pong");
```